# Packaging a Swing application with JavaFX components into an executable JAR

Tags: java, jar, javafx, packaging

I am having trouble packaging an application with both Swing and JavaFX components into a JAR file. Running it from Eclipse is fine. But when executing the Jar, errors occur: The main method is run, which calls the constructor of my app. The constructor calls a `initAndShowGUI()` method, which tries to create a JFXPanel for later addition to a JFrame, but fails with following error message: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\User\bin\glass.dll`. This library seems to be needed by JavaFX but is somehow not loaded. "Pure" JavaFX apps (without Swing) call something like a "preinitialitation" method for JFX that loads all the needed libs, I think (I'm not completely sure). Also, I've found information on how to deploy Java Web Start apps or applets (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_swing_apps.htm), but nothing on "standard" JARs.

Has anybody done this before? I've been looking for a solution a lot but have not been able to find one. Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely your issue is packaging related.

How did you package the app?

For example:

- Did you use [e(fx)clipse](http://efxclipse.org/tut2.html)?
- Did you use the the [javafx ant tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm)?
- Did you use the [javafxpackager](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packager001.htm)?

I know (at least) the last two will work to build a Swing application with JavaFX components into an executable jar.

The SwingInterop sample includes an ant script for packaging the sample into an executable jar.  The sample is downloadable from the [javafx download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html).

I highly recommend reviewing [Why should I use the JavaFX ant tasks for packaging my Swing application?](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_swing_apps_with_integrated) which post also includes the source for the SwingInterop sample build file.